# Upload error does not show up where expected

Tags: php, html, list, dom, upload

Working on a cooking book concept, users can add recipes, and they can upload one image per recipe.

The issue is that when an upload error is displayed, it always shows up in the first `<li>` at the top of the page.

cookbook.php:

```
<ol>
   <li id="bar<?php echo recipe_id ?>">
      <div class="upload_icon" id="upload<?php echo recipe_id ?>"></div>
      <div class="star_icon"></div>
      <div class="share_icon"></div>
      <div class="error_extra" id="error_extra<?php echo $recipe_id?>">
      <?php 
      if (isset($_SESSION['error_message'])) {
      echo $_SESSION['error_message'];
      unset($_SESSION['error_message']); 
      } ?> 
      </div>
   </li>
</ol>
```

upload.php:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST");
//variable declarations
if ($size >= 2097152) {

$_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Your file must be less than 2MB!';           
redirect('cookingbook.php');
exit;
} 
else {
//blablabla
     }
```

If the user is trying to upload an image via the icon `upload478`, the error should appear in  `#bar478`.

How could I make that work ?

Comment: Unless you have a function called `redirect()` this will not work `redirect('cookingbook.php');` and should be `header('Location: cookingbook.php');`

Comment: I have a function redirect(). The redirect works fine.

Comment: Well you have a few options. Remove the `<li>` or instead of doing a redirect, you could use an echo, a popup Alert or use Ajax.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Thanks, I tried to add a JS alert to upload.php but it doesn't work. If you can write an answer with this option, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: You're welcome Ben. It has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a few options.

You can remove the `<li>`, or instead of doing a redirect, you could use an echo, a popup Alert and using Ajax is also an option.